# How to append new dataframe rows to a csv using pandas?

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, append

I have a new dataframe, how to append it to an existed csv?

I tried the following code:

```
f = open('test.csv', 'w')
df.to_csv(f, sep='\t')
f.close()
```

But it doesn't append anything to test.csv. The csv is big, I only want to use append, rather than read the whole csv as dataframe and concatenate it to and write it to a new csv. Is there any good method to solve the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.to_csv('test.csv', sep='\t', header=None, mode='a')
# NOTE:                              ----->  ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: @HavenShi, glad it helps :)

Comment: it seems each row turns to be a single cell, say one of my former row is AAA sunday 200, after append it to csv, there is only a cell which combine all content together like 'AAAsunday200', how to fix that?

Comment: @HavenShi, i can't reproduce this behavior. Could you provide a small reproducible data set?

Comment: Sure. try the following code, it will generate an old file(10 rows) and new file(2 rows) in your local folder. After I append, the new content all mix up:

Comment: @HavenShi, why are you using different separators? First you save your files using default `,` separator and then you are adding new entries using `\t`

Comment: Thank you for reminding me! I tried sep=',' to add new entries, still a new index column (0,1) appears, and the content of the new two rows shift to the second and fifth column lol.

Comment: @HavenShi, try this: `df.to_csv('old_file.csv', header=None, index=False, mode='a')`

Comment: @HavenShi, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 2):

**TL:DR**  Answer from MaxU is correct.

```
df.to_csv('old_file.csv', header=None, mode='a')
```

I had the same problem, wishing to append to DataFrame and save to a CSV inside a loop. It seems to be a common pattern.
My criteria was:

1. Write back to the same file
2. Don't write data more than necessary.
3. Keep appending new data to the dataframe during the loop.
4. Save on each iteration (in case long running loop crashes)
5. Don't store index in the CSV file.

Note the different values of *mode* and *header*. In a complete write, mode='w' and header=True, but in an append, mode='a' and header='False'.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a CSV test file with 3 rows
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 
test_df.to_csv('test.csv', mode='w', header=True, index=False)

# Read CSV into a new frame
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print(df)

# MAIN LOOP
# Create new data in a new DataFrame
for i in range(0, 2):
    newdata = [['jack', i], ['jill', i]] 
    new_df  = pd.DataFrame(newdata, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 

    # Write the new data to the CSV file in append mode
    new_df.to_csv('test.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
    print('check test.csv')

    # Combine the new data into the frame ready for the next loop.
    test_df = pd.concat([test_df, new_df], ignore_index=True)

# At completion, it shouldn't be necessary, but to write the complete data 
test_df.to_csv('completed.csv', mode='w', header=True, index=False)
# completed.csv and test.csv should be identical.
```

Comment: Thanks. I came here looking for a way to append only new data from iterations, didn't realize that I can do this using Series or DF element I'm creating anyways.

Answer (score 1):

To append a pandas dataframe in a csv file, you can also try it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':x, 'Value':y})
with open('CSVFileName.csv', 'a+', newline='') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, index=False, encoding='utf-8', mode='a')
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code, it will generate an old file(10 rows) and new file(2 rows) in your local folder. After I append, the new content all mix up:

```
import pandas as pd
import os 

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("__file__"))
print(dir_path)

raw_data = {'HOUR': [4, 9, 12, 7, 3, 15, 2, 16, 3, 21], 
        'LOCATION': ['CA', 'HI', 'CA', 'IN', 'MA', 'OH', 'OH', 'MN', 'NV', 'NJ'], 
        'TYPE': ['OLD', 'OLD', 'OLD', 'OLD', 'OLD', 'OLD', 'OLD', 'OLD', 'OLD', 'OLD'], 
        'PRICE': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
old_file = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['HOUR', 'LOCATION', 'TYPE', 'PRICE'])
old_file.to_csv(dir_path+"/old_file.csv",index=False)


raw_data = {'HOUR': [2, 22], 
        'LOCATION': ['CA', 'MN'], 
        'TYPE': ['NEW', 'NEW'], 
        'PRICE': [80, 90]}
new_file = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['HOUR', 'LOCATION', 'TYPE', 'PRICE'])
new_file.to_csv(dir_path+"/new_file.csv",index=False)


new_file=dir_path+"/new_file.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(new_file)
df.to_csv('old_file.csv', sep='\t', header=None, mode='a')
```

it will come to:

```
HOUR    LOCATION    TYPE    PRICE
4   CA  OLD 4
9   HI  OLD 24
12  CA  OLD 31
7   IN  OLD 2
3   MA  OLD 3
15  OH  OLD 25
2   OH  OLD 94
16  MN  OLD 57
3   NV  OLD 62
21  NJ  OLD 70
02CANEW80           
122MNNEW90
```

Comment: `df.to_csv('old_file.csv', header=None, mode='a')` should do the trick